# react-countdown-now- prevent re-render when calling setState on parent component

Tags: reactjs, timer, state, countdown

I am pretty new to react and am building a quiz react app. Each quiz has a time limit which is passed via props to a countdown timer component using https://github.com/ndresx/react-countdown

I am storing the time in seconds and the selected answer out of 4 options in the state of the parent component.

The problem is, every time I call `setState` with the selected answer from the child, the timer restarts to the inital state as the entire component re-renders(e.g, quiz starts with 03:00 minutes left, the timer counts down in the meanwhile to 02:00, then the user selects an answer and the timer resets back to 03:00)

I tried implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` in the parent to check if the current time is equal to the initial time, but it prevented any state updates to the entire page(the answer stored in the state marks the selected answer). I also trying using `PureComponent` on the parent but it didn't change the issue.

here's how it looks to illustrate: [image]

Some code:

the parent component with the `selectAnswer` function that sets the state and repsonsible for the issue(props' origin is from a route redirect):

```
class ExamWindow extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
         currentExam: this.props.history.location.state.currentExam,          
     questions:this.props.history.location.state.currentExam.questions,
        timeleft: this.props.history.location.state.currentExam.time,
        selectedAnswers: [],
        currentQuestionIndex: 0,
    }

    selectAnswer = (answerIndex) => {
        let newSelectedAnswers = [...this.state.selectedAnswers];
       newSelectedAnswers[this.state.currentQuestionIndex] = answerIndex;

    this.setState((state, props) => ({
        selectedAnswers: newSelectedAnswers,
        timeleft: state.timeleft
    }));

}
}
```

the component that stores the timer(in parent's `render()`):

```
<ExamInfoBox currentQuestionNumber={this.state.currentQuestionIndex+1} 
             totalQuestionsAmount={this.state.questions.length}
             time={this.state.timeleft}
>
</ExamInfoBox>
```

the component that contains the exam answers

```
Answers = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="exam-answers">
            { 
                times(4, (i) => {
                    return (
                        <div className={classNames("exam-answer", this.isSelected(i+1) ? 'active' : '')}
                        key={i} 
                        onClick={() => this.selectAnswer(i+1)}>
                            <span className='answer'>
                                {i}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

the component that contains the exam answers(in parent's `render()`)

```
<this.Answers question={props.question}/>
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Can you share a running example?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Questions = ({ onStagePass,stageNum}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Stage Number {stageNum}
      <button onClick={onStagePass}>
        Next Stage
      </button>
    </div>
  )
};

export const Exam = () => {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(400);
  const [stageNum, setStageNum] = useState(1);

  useEffect( () => {
    const timerInterval = setInterval(() => setTimeLeft(timeLeft => timeLeft -1),1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timerInterval);  
  },[]);

  return (
  <div>
      Time Left: {timeLeft}
      <Questions onStagePass={() => setStageNum(stageNum+1)} stageNum={stageNum} />
    </div>
  )
};
```